# React updating state creates duplicate element in DOM but state updates correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with a method to add/create a new sub-component and insert it into an array at a specific index (i.e. [elem1, elem2, elem3] becomes [elem1, elem2, new elem, elem3]).

When using something like array.splice(currentIndex + 1, 0, newElement), in the DOM the last element that already exists is just duplicated, though it appears to update correctly for the array in state.

The only way I have found that works is to just use array.push(newElement), which does render properly but is not the desired effect. I've tried a few more ways of inserting the new element into the array but so far everything other than .push() causes the duplication issue. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
    const Notef = ({ fetchedParts }) => {

    const [parts, setParts] = useState(fetchedParts);

    const addNewPart = (currentPart) => {
        const index = parts.map((p) => p.id).indexOf(currentPart.id);
        const updatedParts = [...parts];
        const newPart = { id: pid(), html: 'Type here...', tag: 'p' }
        // This will cause duplicated element
        updatedParts.splice(index + 1, 0, newPart);
        // This does not create duplicate
        //updatedParts.push(newPart);
        setParts(updatedParts);
    }

    return (
        <> 
            {parts.map((part) => {
                const position =  parts.map((p) => p.id).indexOf(part.id) + 1;
                return (
                    <Part
                        key={part.id}
                        position={position}
                        id={part.id}
                        tag={part.tag}
                        html={part.html}
                        addPart={addNewPart}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
}

export default Notef;
```

[Element duplication w/ .splice()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0bo8.png)

[Element addition w/ .push()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwq1k.png)

*edit: re-worded intro to specify new element to be inserted rather than replaced.*

Comment: Don't use indexes for keys: `key={part.id}`. Use `parts.find` instead of `parts.map((p) => p.id).indexOf(currentPart.id)`, you're iterating twice and mapping to a new array pointlessly. You can just do `updatedParts[index] = ...` to replace.

Comment: @Dominic Thank you for the input, this will definitely help clean up the code a bit! I've removed the use of indexes for keys.  For the final suggestion though, I will update my post to be more specific. I'm trying to insert a new object at a specific index, not replace the existing one!

Comment: @Dominic Just re-ran things and turns out removing the use of Indexes alone actually fixed the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Dominic found the issue - I was using indices for keys in the rendered component. Replaced that with the ID and it solved the issue!

```
return (
    <> 
        {parts.map((part) => {
            const position =  parts.map((p) => p.id).indexOf(part.id) + 1;
            return (
                <Part
                    key={part.id}
                    position={position}
                    id={part.id}
                    tag={part.tag}
                    html={part.html}
                    addPart={addNewPart}
                />
            );
        })}
    </>
);
```